# How can I cache a has-many relationship with entity 6 framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that is written on the top of ASP.NET MVC5 framework along side with Entity 6 Framework.

Typically, caching relations does isn't helpful. However, I have a case where the related data never change, but the parent does. I am looking for a way to cache the relations only so I don't have to make hard read each time the page is loaded.

I have the following two classes

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRecord> Records { get; set; }
}

public class ItemRecord 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Item")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public virtual ItemRecord Item { get; set; }
}
```

Within my `Index` action in the controller, I can get the data using the following linq statement.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    if(id.HasValue) 
    {
        var items = Context.Items.Where(item => item.CategoryId == id.Value)
                                 .Include(x => x.Records)
                                 .ToList();
    }
    ....
}
```

Since the `Item` model changes all the time, I don't want to cache it. However, I want to cache all the data in `Records` relation since it never changes and it is large data set.

**Question**
How can I cache the `Records` relation in my above example?

I tried to use `OutputCache` attribute to cache the relation like so

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "CategoryId", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRecord> Records { get; set; }
}
```

as you can tell that did not work, this is the error I got

> Attribute 'OutputCache' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'class, method' declarations.

Apparently `OutputCache` is for caching classes not entity relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `OutputCache` is for caching the response of an action. It literally caches the whole response so the action itself does not have to be run. It is not appropriate for scenarios where you just want to cache particular data.

For that, you need something like `MemoryCache` or a NoSQL solution like Redis. `MemoryCache` is generally easier to use, but has important limitations:

1. As its name implies, the cache is in-memory, and therefore only survives as long as the memory is reserved. Namely, restarting the server, or simply having the AppPool stop, either as part of normal recycling, explicit shutdown, or crashing, will wipe everything you've cached. It will also be effected by normal memory optimization. If for example, the OS needs to reclaim memory for another process, the cache will be one of the first things to be sacrificed.
2. It's process-bound, if you're utilizing multiple processes (web garden), the cache will be unique per process, which could mean including the same data in memory multiple times, once for each process.

If you want a more stable cache, you'd need to use something like Redis, which while also an in-memory system, is backed by the filesystem and can also be distributed. That means you can have it running on a totally different server or even multiple different servers for failover redundancy. This will be a little more difficult to implement, as you have to actually set up Redis and configure the connection to it, but I specifically recommend Redis, here, because Microsoft has done a lot of work already to ensure it plays well both with Windows and with things like ASP.NET applications. Redis is actually the backing behind Azure Cache, so they're motivated both to make it seamless and keep on top of updates and such.

Comment: Thank you for this helps. isn't there a built in library that allow me to use Redis to cache the relations? or is this something I would have to write from scratch?

Comment: Not a built-in library, but there are clients available as Nugets. I used the Stack Exchange client (https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/)

Comment: This is great. I am just trying to understand the workflow before I start using the package. How would I use this package to cache the results of the relation?

Comment: More likely than not, you'd want to combine that with StackExchange.Redis.Extensions (https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions) which has a more `MemoryCache`-like API and supports things like serialization, allowing you to add whole objects as JSON strings, for example, and deserialize those back out into objects.

Comment: Since you posted this answer and I have been researching for a solution around your recommendation. I am trying to figure out how I would cache the relation in entity framework but... no luck. This blog "link below" explains how to use `Redis` with `ICacheProvider` to interact with the `Redis` server. But I am not sure how I would use that to cache my `Records` relation listed in the question. Do I need to use Lazy loading instead to accomplish this? I am hoping to keep using Eager loading to get the job done. http://blog.chudinov.net/asp-net-caching-and-sessions-with-redis-and-cachemanager/

Comment: Since you have to query the single entity either way, I'd recommend doing two separately queries (what's referred to as explicit loading). Query the single entity, then check the cache for the related entities. If not present, explicitly load the related entities, and add them to the cache. That way, most times, you'll still only have the single query.

Comment: What if a new item was added? Do I have to delete the cache then forcing everything to be loaded?

Comment: Well, that's the nature of a cache. You can either set an expires on the cache entry, such that items may be stale for a time, but will eventually be updated, or you would need to invalidate the cache when some change is made, so an update is forced.